# Windows XP - hook into touchscreen event?

Tags: windows-xp, touchscreen

I'm working on a touchscreen product that's deployed on Windows XP.  I would like to be able to trap the event of the user pressing and holding down a certain area of the touchscreen for a certain period of time.  Is there a low level way I can hook into Windows to capture an event like this?

TY,
Fred

Comment: Wouldn't the touch part of the screen effectively be like a mouse, in otherwords could you look for mousedown/mousemove type events?
Are you trying to catch events outside of your apps window?

Comment: The touchscreen presses should end up as mouseup/down events yes.  The application on my system is browser based, so IE has the focus pretty much all the time.  I'd like to hook into the events somehow so that I can capture them regardless of what has the focus however.

Answer (score 1):

I would be extremely surprised if this was available. You can get some of the messages related to IE (windows resize etc and windows move in early versions) but I think that's it.

Thinking about it letting Webpages get very jiggy with the host OS would be asking for trouble.

If you have full control of the deployment environment (sounds like they might be workstations or terminal that you deploy?) your best bet might be to resort to somelike like ActiveX controls downloaded to the client to hook your messages for you and feed back from there in some way.

Comment: It is a messy requirement yes.  My current plan is to use the Windows hook functionality and get notified of windows mouse events.  I should be able to do that by writing a DLL in C.  To make it even more complex I then need to have that call back to the main app. in Java :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using SetWindowsHookEx Function  and WH_MOUSE_LL(value 13) in place of idHook parameter to hook mouse events
More info at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804